# Go - How to combine multiple error objects

Tags: go

Say I have the following code:

```golang
package lib

import (
    "errors"
    "strconv"
)

var ErrSomething = errors.New("foobar")

func SomeFunc(str string) (int, error) {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(str)
    if err != nil {
        // how to combine ErrSomething with err?
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("%w: %w", ErrSomething, err)
    }
    
    // do other things, potentially return other errors

    return i

}
```

How do I combine the error returned from `strconv.Atoi` with my named error `ErrSomething`. The reason for combining is so that users of my `SomeFunc()` can check what exactly went wrong using my error "constants" while not losing information about the underlying error.

I have read similar questions but the usual answer is to just do: `return 0, fmt.Errorf("foobar: %w", err)` but this way my users can't check the error using `errors.Is(err, ???)`

Comment: You might be interested in the following library: https://github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror

Comment: It seems that `Errorf` can only wrap 1 error. Have you tried to turn the underlying error to string: `fmt.Errorf("%w: %s", ErrSomething, err)` ?

Comment: On multiple errors, see also the future (Go 1.2x, for 2023) with a [slice/tree of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73758530/6309) which does include a `Join()` method.

Comment: With Go 1.20 there is `errors.Join()`: https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.20#errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior by creating an error type that implements the `Is` and `Unwrap` methods as follows:

```golang
package lib

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type FoobarError struct {
    msg      string
    original error
}

func (err *FoobarError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", err.msg, err.original.Error())
}

func (err *FoobarError) Unwrap() error {
    return err.original
}

func (err *FoobarError) Is(target error) bool {
    _, ok := target.(*FoobarError)
    return ok
}

func SomeFunc() error {
    // strconv.ErrSyntax is used as a dummy error here for the error
    // that might be returned by strconv.Atoi or any other operation.
    err := strconv.ErrSyntax
    return &FoobarError{"foobar", err}
}
```

Usage:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "lib"
)

func main() {
    if err := lib.SomeFunc(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)                                // foobar: invalid syntax
        fmt.Println(errors.Is(err, &lib.FoobarError{})) // true
        fmt.Println(errors.Is(err, strconv.ErrSyntax))  // true
    }
}
```

You can read more about this approach [here](https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors).

## Bonus

Similar to Go's [os.IsExist](https://pkg.go.dev/os#IsExist), you may be interested in adding a helper function to your library that makes it easier for the user to check the error:

```golang
package lib

import (
  "errors"
  // ...
)

// ...

func IsFoobar(err error) bool {
    return errors.Is(err, &FoobarError{})
}
```

Usage:

```golang
package main

// ...

func main() {
    err := lib.SomeFunc(); 
    if lib.IsFoobar(err) {
      // ...
    }
}
```